# Rank of matrices $A,B$ where $B^T A = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Problem:

> Show that if $B^T A = 0$, then
>   $$\DeclareMathOperator{\rank}{rank}
> \rank A + \rank B = \rank [A \mid B]$$

This would mean that $ c(A) \cap c( B ) = \lbrace 0 \rbrace $. Where $c(\cdot)$ means the column space. But I have no idea how to use the assumption about the product of these matrices.

Could you give me a hint?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Suppose that $v\in c(A)\cap c(B)$.  Then, there is some $x$ so that $v=Ax$ and $y$ so that $v=By$.  Now, consider $y^TB^TAx=v^Tv=\|v\|^2$.  Since $B^TA=0$, this means that $\|v\|^2=0$, hence $v=0$.  Hence, the intersection $c(A)\cap c(B)$ is $\{0\}$.

Now, $c([A|B])=c(A)+c(B)$ and using inclusion/exclusion, the result follows.

Answer (score 0):

let $A$ be in $R^{m\times n}$ and ti has $rank(A) = r.$ it is always true that $rank([A|b]) \le rank(A) + rank(B).$ to show that $rank(A) + rank(B) \le rank([A|B])$ we will use the fact that $B^\top A = 0$ implies that column space of $B$ is contained in the left null space of $A.$ that is the rank of $A$ is less or equal to the dimension $m-r$ of the left null space. that is 
$$ rank(A) + rank(B) \le r + m-r=m=\text{number of rowsof $[A|B]$} \le rank([A|B])$$ and we are done.